# Запустить программу от имени администратора из батника

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Мне нужно сделать батник, который будет запускать приложение от имени Администратора.
Пользователь, от который будет запускать батник, прав админа не имеет.
Нужно запихнуть пароль в сам батник ( он будет сконвертирован в exe, так что пароль не будет виден).
`runas /savecred /user:Администратор<программа>`  - не вариант, т.к. пользователь сможет запускать другие программы.
`echo <пароль> | runas /netonly /user:Администратор <программа>` - программу запускает, но прав админа не дает. Без /netonly не запускает.
Также, если батником это сделать невозможно, подскажите альтернативы без использования стороннего ПО.